# Use of ORDER BY returns column filled with NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to do the following exercise:

> Write a SQL query to list the names of all people who starred in a movie released in 2004, ordered by birth year. Your query should output a table with a single column for the name of each person. People with the same birth year may be listed in any order. No need to worry about people who have no birth year listed, so long as those who do have a birth year are listed in order. If a person appeared in more than one movie in 2004, they should only appear in your results once.

I have the following schema in my `movies.db` database:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, birth
FROM people
WHERE id IN (    
    SELECT person_id
    FROM stars
    WHERE movie_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM movies
        WHERE year = 2004
    )
)
ORDER BY birth;
```

I get a column filled with NULL values:

[image]

However, if I leave out the line `ORDER BY birth`, that column shows the values correctly (although unsorted). What should I do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?

Comment: Do you only get 5 rows returned? What happens if you do `ORDER BY birth DESC`?

Comment: did you want the NULLs to be the last ones?

Comment: Thank you all. I only copied the first 5 rows. The database has thousands of rows. I know understand why NULL comes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorted normally, the NULL's are considered as lowest values.
So when you order ascending (the default) then the NULL's come first.

But the field `birth` is a numeric type.
So sorting the negative value DESCENDING will push those pesky nullies down.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, birth
FROM people
WHERE id IN (    
    SELECT person_id
    FROM stars
    WHERE movie_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM movies
        WHERE year = 2004
    )
)
ORDER BY -birth DESC;
```

**Simplified test**

> ```
> create table people (id integer primary key, birth int)
>
> insert into people (birth) values (100),(42),(16),(null)
> ```

> ```
> select * from people
> order by -birth desc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | birth
> -: | ----:
>  3 |    16
>  2 |    42
>  1 |   100
>  4 |  null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=91a6eb27cd79b0402218f913abffdc7b)*

And another way is to change the null's to an impossible high value.

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(birth, 999)
```

Or use the newer `ASC NULLS LAST` syntax.

```
ORDER BY birth ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: `-null` is `null`. Why do you think the `-` sign makes any difference?

Comment: @forpas It's because of the DESCENDING. And -null is as low as null.

Comment: SQLite supports NULLS LAST at the ORDER BY clause, so all this is redundant. The OP mentions: *I get a column filled with NULL values*, but you assume that there are non null values.

Comment: She did mention that she has values without the order by. But ok, NULLS LAST is a better solution i.m.h.o., if her Sqlite supports it (SQLite 3.30 I think)

Comment: Thank you, @LukStorms. It works perfectly, now. By the way, I am a "he".

Comment: Thanks. And sorry.

Comment: Btw, try if the nulls last syntax works for your version. `order by birth asc nulls last`  It's easier to understand than the negative birth.

Comment: Works great, @LukStorms ! Thank you for the suggestion !

Comment: @F.Zer you mention * I get a column filled with NULL values*. Doesn't this mean that you don't get any non null values?

Comment: @forpas No, I do have non NULL values. I thought the _whole_ column was filled with NULL values. However, I had to scroll 100 pages to find out non NULL value were actually there. Thank you for your excellent suggestion about "NULLS LAST" !

Comment: @F.Zer this is why I voted to close your question as not reproducible.

Comment: @forpas Thanks for the clarification. By the way, I am now enjoying your "NULLS LAST" suggestion in my queries.